# Spring Tool Suite- referencing projects

Tags: java, spring, maven

I come from a C#\Visual Studio background and can't wrap my head around how to reference project B from project A such that when I do a Maven build, it actually builds. Using Spring Tool Suite:

1. In Project A, Properties> Java Build Path > Projects, I've added Project B.
2. Project B builds via Maven just fine as a package.
3. Lovely, intellisense works and I'm happily coding along.
4. I go to do a Maven build on project A and get a whole bunch of `[ERROR]: ...package [project B] does not exist.`

I get that somehow i need to make Maven aware of project B's jar...but I don't understand how this works. I don't think i want to force the jar into my local Maven repo (if i do, then what happens when i use the company's maven repo?), i really just want to have maven pick up the .class files from project B's build and be on my merry way. What am I missing?

EDIT: adding poms:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.firm</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

POM 2:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.firm</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

    </plugins>
  </build>
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you build a project via maven it automatically being added to maven local repository and you can reference it from any maven project inside pom.xml.
Please attach pom files for both project.

Edit:
add this dependency to projectA pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.firm</groupId>
                <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added the poms - any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: You have to add projectB as dependency in projectA pom.xml.
add this pom file:
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.firm</groupId>
                <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: i've never had this issue before, but maven is complaining that it can't download the maven-install-plugin because it "Failed to authenticate with proxy", although all other dependencies and plugins load fine? I doubt anyone can help, but thought i'd ask! I'm almost there.

Comment: I figured it out - refreshed https credentials on my local proxy server, and everything flowed in. Thanks!